# bind mouseout with jquery in ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, mouseevent, jquery

I need to rebind mouseout event in jquery because when mouse go to a child of main div (what i have binded the mouseout event), mouseout event is called and I don't want it. So i do this:

```
$('.div-hidden').live('mouseout', function (event) {
    e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    if (e.parentNode.parentNode == this || e == this || e.parentNode == this) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(this).parent().css('overflow') == "visible") {
        var parent_height = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().css('height').substr(0, $(this).css('height').length), 10);
        $(this).parent().animate({
            top: (parent_height - 40) + "px"
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        });
    }
});
```

This works good in ie8/9 and others browser, but not in ie7. I also tried to change live() with bind() but it doesn't work. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want mouseleave event instead:

```
$('.div-hidden').live('mouseleave', function (event) {
    if ($(this).parent().css('overflow') == "visible") {
        var parent_height = parseInt($(this).parent().parent().css('height').substr(0, $(this).css('height').length), 10);
        $(this).parent().animate({
            top: (parent_height - 40) + "px"
        }, 500, function () {
            $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        });
    }
});
```

You should not use `.live` unless your jQuery version is < 1.4.2 or something.

Comment: it doesn't work anyway with ie7. .div-hidden parent has position relative. Is it a problem?

Comment: @pindol Do you have a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're better to use mouseenter / mouseleave events in this case?